# Cross section from the scattering amplitude with derivative

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Suppose we have a process with two particles in and two particles out. The amplitude for such process is given by

$$ M_0 (2\pi)^4 \delta(p'+l_2-l_1-p)+M_1 (2\pi)^4 \delta_{1,2,-}(p'+l_2-l_1-p)\delta_+'(p'+l_2-l_1-p)$$

where $x^{\pm} = x^0 \pm x^3$ are lightfront coordinates. $M_0$ is the leading contribution, and $M_1$ is a correction to the amplitude. Unlike the first term, the correction has the derivative of a delta function.

How can one compute the cross section from this?

Comment: What is the theory you are considering? How did you get these formulas?

Comment: This is strong field QED, electron/photon scattering in a constant field with low photon energy